# Character Jump using Box2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am using box2d and cocos2d for my jump based game. I need to jump the character on platforms as they come.

Any ideas of how to do it using box2d ?

Comment: your question is very broad, you are practically asking for us to tell you how to make the game in its entirety. what have YOU done so far to attempt to do this on your own? where specifically are you struggling.

Comment: I have a spritesheet and plist for its metadata. I need to make a charactee jump.. I can make it walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this:

```
//OBSTACLE_1:
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hungObstacle1_C2H18.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(1568,704);
        sprite.tag = 4;
        [self addChild:sprite];

        //SHAPE :
        {
            b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
            bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            bodyDefinition.position.Set(1568/PTM_RATIO, 704/PTM_RATIO);
            bodyDefinition.userData = sprite;

            body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDefinition);//body is a b2Body

            // Create body shape
            b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
        //row 1, col 1
        int num = 8;
        b2Vec2 verts[] = {
            b2Vec2(14.5f / PTM_RATIO, -27.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(19.5f / PTM_RATIO, -11.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(19.5f / PTM_RATIO, 11.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(16.5f / PTM_RATIO, 24.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-14.5f / PTM_RATIO, 24.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-19.5f / PTM_RATIO, 16.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-19.5f / PTM_RATIO, -13.0f / PTM_RATIO),
            b2Vec2(-12.5f / PTM_RATIO, -26.0f / PTM_RATIO)
        };
        bodyShape.Set(verts, num);

            // Create shape definition and add to body
            b2FixtureDef bodyFixtureDefinition;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.shape = &bodyShape;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.density = 5000.0f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.friction = 1.0f;
            bodyFixtureDefinition.restitution = 1.0f;//*        
            fixture=body->CreateFixture(&bodyFixtureDefinition);            
        }           
    }
```

*NOTE:by setting **restitution** to 1 body will keep jumping all the time just need little force

Answer (score 0):

To simulate jumping, you can use the cpBodyApplyImpulse method and apply a force in a straight up direction. Assuming you've got gravity enabled, this should provide an accuracte simulation, although you may need to tweak it. For example, here is a line from a recent project of mine.

```
cpBodyApplyImpulse(charBody, cpv(0.0, -25 * scale), charBody->p);
```

This is making the sprite represented by the charBody jump.